# Теорема пифагора на больших числах

Tags: математика

Как нам известно у процессора есть ограничение на обрабатываемые числа. Мне нужно узнать длину гипотенузы, соответственно я использую такую формулу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это не сработает с очень большими числами

Как быть?

Comment: Перейти на длинную арифметику, например... *с очень большими числами* - целыми или с плавающей точкой? И какая нужна точность?

Comment: Опять же никто не мешает отмасштабироваться: `Hyp(x, y) = k * Hyp(x/k, y/k)`.

Comment: А ведь правда, число можно сократить.

Comment: Тут вопрос точности, а не размера чисел.

Comment: Уточните в вопросе, что такое для вас "большие числа"

Comment: Если вопрос в простом увеличении точности вычислений, может поможет вот эта ссылка [easydan.com](http://easydan.com/arts/2016/pyfloats-comp/). Это в смысле вычислений с большими числами, не только решение теоремы Пифагора.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. **Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.**

Comment: Если вы работаете в C/C++, а ваши числа влазят в стандартные типы (скажем, double) - то к вашим услугам функция `hypot`...